# advance filter expression in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I couldn't get any solution yet that's why questioning...

I have a table where two fields are **categoryID_A, categoryID_B**. I have some category ids like **'df23a5', '234za2', 'k0f9e3'**. Need to get filtered out rows from that table including eighter the categoryID_A or categoryID_B matches with those ids.

```
...
FilterExpression: 'createdAt >= :time_within AND createdAt <= :from_time AND (categoryID_A IN (:m1,:m2,:m3) OR categoryID_B IN (:m1,:m2,:m3))',
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ':from_time': '2022-10-10T02:44:12.481Z',
  ':time_within': '2022-11-11T02:44:12.481Z',
  ':m1': 'df23a5',
  ':m2': '234za2',
  ':m3': 'k0f9e3'
}
...
```

Comment: It seem you are doing correctly, except `createdAt` condition. I think it should look like  `createdAt >= :from_time AND createdAt <= :time_within`

Comment: Yes. May you're correct. My issue is solved.